how to set CallType notification with default ringtone set for calls
I am using fcm push notification to start the calls and the connect to socket and webrtc.
I have set the normal flow with notificationChannel and set sound for that, but its still sound for default notification sound rather than the call ringtone sound. any help will be appreciated Thanks in advance
below is the code
fun createNotification(context: Context, contactInfo: UserDetail)
        {
            val intent = Intent(context, VideoCallActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("Contact", contactInfo)
            intent.putExtra("notificationId", INCOMING_CALL_NOTIFICATION_ID)
            intent.putExtra("inComingCall", true)
            val acceptCallIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, REQUEST_CODE_ACCEPT_CALL, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

            val rejectIntent = Intent(context, HomeActivity::class.java)
            rejectIntent.putExtra("Contact", contactInfo)
            rejectIntent.putExtra("notificationId", INCOMING_CALL_NOTIFICATION_ID)
            rejectIntent.putExtra("fromCall", true)
            rejectIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            val rejectCallIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, REQUEST_CODE_REJECT_CALL, rejectIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

            val ringingIntent = Intent(context, RingingActivity::class.java)
            ringingIntent.putExtra("Contact", contactInfo)
            ringingIntent.putExtra("notificationId", INCOMING_CALL_NOTIFICATION_ID)
            ringingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
            val ringingCallIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, REQUEST_CODE_RINGING_CALL, ringingIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

            setupNotification(context, contactInfo, acceptCallIntent, rejectCallIntent, ringingCallIntent, AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.profile_avatar))
        }

private fun setupNotification(
            context: Context,
            contactInfo: UserDetail,
            acceptCallIntent: PendingIntent,
            rejectCallIntent: PendingIntent,
            ringingCallIntent: PendingIntent,
            resource: Drawable?
        ) {
            val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

            val channelId = createNotificationChannel(context, notificationManager)

            val name = contactInfo.name


            val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId!!)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.incoming_call))
                .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.incoming_call_from, name))
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setFullScreenIntent(ringingCallIntent, true)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setVibrate(longArrayOf(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000))
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE))


            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
            {
                val icon = IconCompat.createWithBitmap(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.profile_avatar))
                val caller = Person.Builder()
                    .setIcon(icon)
                    .setName(name)
                    .setImportant(true)
                    .build()

                val notificationStyle = NotificationCompat.CallStyle.forIncomingCall(caller, rejectCallIntent, acceptCallIntent).setIsVideo(true)
                builder.setStyle(notificationStyle)
            }
            else
            {
                builder.addAction(
                    R.drawable.ic_answer, "Accept", acceptCallIntent
                )
                builder.addAction(
                        R.drawable.ic_reject, "Reject", rejectCallIntent
                    )
            }

            builder.setLargeIcon(defaultAvatar)

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    context,
                    Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
                ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                notificationManager.notify(INCOMING_CALL_NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build())
            }
        }

private fun createNotificationChannel(context: Context, notificationManager: NotificationManager): String?
        {
            val ringtoneUri: Uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE)
            val audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE)
                .build()

            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                INCOMING_CALL_CHANNEL_ID,
                "Incoming Call Notifications",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            ).apply {
                description = "Channel for incoming call notifications"
                enableLights(true)
                enableVibration(true)
                lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC
                setSound(ringtoneUri, audioAttributes)
            }

I have tried even to copied the ringtone file to cache and the use, it can play ringtone manager but its uri is not able to use in notification.
Any help will be appreciated
